# Extracting json payload in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a file like below. As you can see there are few lines/contents between curly braces. As there is multiple group of opened and closed curly braces, I want to get the content between the curly brances ({ and } ) for each line separatly.

## Sample file:

```
{
   "/tmp/©ƒ-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/crds.yaml": [
   ],
   "/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/deployment.yaml": [
   ],
   "/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/restic-daemonset.yaml": [
   ],
   "/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/secret.yaml": [
   ]
 }
 {
   "/tmp/autoscaler-fb12fa7a-cluster-autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/templates/deployment.yaml": [
     ".spec.replicas: '2' != '0'",
   ],
   "/tmp/autoscaler-fb12fa7a-cluster-autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/templates/servicemonitor.yaml": [
     "error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"ServiceMonitor\"\n"
   ]
 }
 {
   "/tmp/metrics-server-1960953a-metrics-server-certs/raw/templates/resources.yaml": [
     "error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"Issuer\"\n",
     "error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"Certificate\"\n"
   ]
 }
```

Expected result: Need 3 seperated data chunks which is between the curly braces.

Could someone help me here?

Comment: Consider posting exact output from the given input, to avoid misunderstanding of what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sequence of valid JSON objects, you can use `jq` to easily and robustly process them:

Given `file.jsons`:

```
{
   "/tmp/©ƒ-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/crds.yaml": [ ""
   ],
   "/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/deployment.yaml": [ ""
   ],
   "/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/restic-daemonset.yaml": [ ""
   ],
   "/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/secret.yaml": [ ""
   ]
 }
 {
   "/tmp/autoscaler-fb12fa7a-cluster-autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/templates/deployment.yaml": [
     ".spec.replicas: '2' != '0'"
   ],
   "/tmp/autoscaler-fb12fa7a-cluster-autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/templates/servicemonitor.yaml": [
     "error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"ServiceMonitor\"\n"
   ]
 }
 {
   "/tmp/metrics-server-1960953a-metrics-server-certs/raw/templates/resources.yaml": [
     "error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"Issuer\"\n",
     "error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"Certificate\"\n"
   ]
 }
```

You can for example reformat each object as a single line:

```
$ jq -s -r 'map(@json) | join("\n")' < file.jsons 
{"/tmp/©ƒ-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/crds.yaml":[""],"/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/deployment.yaml":[""],"/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/restic-daemonset.yaml":[""],"/tmp/velero-4bf57ed2-velero/velero/templates/secret.yaml":[""]}
{"/tmp/autoscaler-fb12fa7a-cluster-autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/templates/deployment.yaml":[".spec.replicas: '2' != '0'"],"/tmp/autoscaler-fb12fa7a-cluster-autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler/templates/servicemonitor.yaml":["error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"ServiceMonitor\"\n"]}
{"/tmp/metrics-server-1960953a-metrics-server-certs/raw/templates/resources.yaml":["error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"Issuer\"\n","error: the server doesn't have a resource type \"Certificate\"\n"]}
```

Now you can process it line by line without having to worry about matching up curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion, the above jq would not work for all the json payload . For example for below json payload it is giving an error

```
 {
   "/tmp/ingress-dae7bd30-ingress-internet/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-deployment.yaml": [
     ".spec.replicas: '2' != '3'",
   ],
   "/tmp/ingress-dae7bd30-ingress-internet/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-metrics-service.yaml": [
     ".spec.clusterIP: '' != '10.3.24.53'"
   ],
   "/tmp/ingress-dae7bd30-ingress-internet/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-service.yaml": [
     ".spec.clusterIP: '' != '10.3.115.118'"
   ],
   "/tmp/ingress-dae7bd30-ingress-internet/nginx-ingress/templates/controller-stats-service.yaml": [
     ".spec.clusterIP: '' != '10.3.115.30'"
   ],
   "/tmp/ingress-dae7bd30-ingress-internet/nginx-ingress/templates/default-backend-deployment.yaml": [
   ]
 }
```

Comment: Please consider providing feedback to specific answer as comment to that answer, instead of posting it as a different answer.